# How to test a socket call in ts.ed?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Goal: I want to make a test where given a certain value received from a client, my socket return the correct answer.

I have a service which manage sockets. I want to test the return value of a specific call, made from the client through a socket, to this service.
My problem is Ts.ed use a lot of decorators and I don't know how to mimic this behavior.

Here is the code from MyService.service:

```
@SocketService('/folder1/folder2')
export class MyService {
   @Nsp nsp!: SocketIO.Namespace

   @Input('subscribeOrders')
   @Emit(SocketMessage.ORDERS)
   async subscribeOrders(@Args(0) site: string @Socket socket: Socket) {
      // do things with site param
      return myValue
   }
```

And this is my test file so far:

```
describe('MyService', () => {
   beforeEach(PlatformTest.create)
   afterEach(PlatformTest.reset)

   it('should be subscribed to rooms', () => {
      const service = PlatformTest.get<MyService>(MyService)
      const socket = "ThisIsWhereIWouldPutMySocketIfIHadOne"
      const myValueToTest = service.subscribeOrders('site', socket)

      expect(myValueToTest).toBe(true)
   })
})
```

In a real case, the socket param is directly filled by some decorator/ framework magic. But I dont know how to mimic it in my tests.
It is also possible that all my approach is wrong, and if it is the case I would be glad to hear of a better way.